# Making a JS card game

Tags: javascript

As the title suggests, I'm trying to make a browser card game using a standard deck of 52 cards. I'm trying to not to use others' code and do as much as I can on my own. I made a rough plan of what I think I need to make for now.

1. Make a card object. The card object will contain the values of it's number and it's suit.
2. Make a deck object. The deck contains an array of card objects, and has the functions shuffle and deal, which both manipulate the array. Shuffle will rearrange the cards, deal will pop() an amount of cards to a player's hand.
3. Make a playerHand array. The array will hold the card objects drawn by the player from the deck object.
4. Make a botHand array. Same as playerHand but for opponent (bot).

I just started and am already stuck. I made a Card constructor, and am now working on making the deck object. My main question is how would I create an array inside the deck object that essentially uses the Card constructor I made 52 times. I assume I'd just run a for loop but not sure about proper syntax. This is what I have so far, also any other suggestions for my logic to making the game would be greatly appreciated.

```
function Card(value, suit) {
    this.value = value;
    this.suit = suit;
}

var deck = {
    cards: new Array(52),

    shuffle: function() {

    },

    deal: function() {

    }
}
```

Comment: What about the syntax of a `for` loop are you not sure about? What have you tried?

Comment: I believe you made this more difficult that it needs to be. Instead of using a Card constructor just use the numbers 1-52 and assign each range a suit. For instance 1-13 is hearts. Then you could just create an array of numbers and find a way to randomise the order. I don't know if that solves your issue since you might actually want to use the constructor.

Comment: For the for loop I think I would do something like this right?


for(var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
Card(i, hearts);
Card(i, diamonds);
Card(i, spades);
Card(i, clubs);
}


I'm just not sure how to then pass these values into the array, and how would I store that array in a variable inside the deck object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but, you could do:

```
for (let i = 1; i < 14; i++){
    cards.push(Card(i, 'Spade'));
    cards.push(Card(i, 'Diamond'));
    cards.push(Card(i, 'Clubs'));
    cards.push(Card(i, 'Hearts'));
}
```

The cards array would then have 52 card objects, in the order of:
`1 of Spades, 1 of Diamonds, 1 of Clubs, 1 of hearts, 2 of Spades, 2 of Diamonds....`

Comment: Yeah this would work for adding to the array, but my main issue is where do I put this for loop if that makes sense?

Comment: You could put it in the constructor so that it runs whenever you create an instance of the Deck object

Comment: I see, that explains it. I'm really new to using objects so I'm having trouble thinking about them. Thank you.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help